# Conditional Probability

Tags: r, conditional-statements, probability

I am trying to create a matrix of the conditional probabilities from this:

I have rewritten the code without the loop

```
a # Signal Vector 
b # Price Change Vector
Signalt<- seq(0, 1, 0.05) # Produce the 5% tiles
abst <- c(seq(1, 1.02,  by = 0.0025), 2)  #Produce the 0% to 2% tiles with 0.25% increments. Added 1 to include price change of 0 in `temp` 

xbool = ((Signal >= Signalt[1] & a < Signalt[1 + 1])  *1) # 1 for True 0 for False 
temp = (PercChange + 1)  * xbool
temp2 <- temp[which(temp > 0)]
CondProb <- cut(temp2, abst, include.lowest = T)
table(CondProb)
```

This outputs the table with abst columns with the number of occurences. 
I of course need it to be in % of total per row, but I would like first to be able to run the loop and get the matrix output.

---

Loop Original - Should be largely ignored as I have changed most of the coding setup

```
Signal <- runif(100)
PercChange <- abs((rnorm(100)/100))
signalt <- seq(0, 1, 0.05)
abst <- seq(0, c(0.02:1), 0.0025)



CondDistMat <- matrix(0, nrow = length(signalt), ncol = length(abst))

for(j in 1:length(signalt - 1)){
    xbool = (is.na((Signal >= signalt[j] & Signal < signalt[j + 1]) ) * 1)
    ysubset =  (PercChange * xbool[j] )
    CondProb = hist(ysubset, breaks = abst, freq = TRUE)
    CondDistMat[signalt, abst] <- CondProb$density 
}
```

The columns will be the percentiles defined by `abst` while the rows will be 5% tiles defined by `signalt`. The idea is through the boolean vector to produce 1's where the absolute returns `PercChange` should be in the columns, and then plot the probabilities for each `signalt` of this.

I am however not being able to produce an output - can anyone spot the error(s)?
Thanks in advance

The desired output should look something like the attached image[image: Conditional Probabilities].

Comment: Any help is much appreciated, I am a bit stuck on this!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `cut` or `findInterval`

An example of what the output looks like with these functions

```
> cut(rnorm(9), breaks = -6:6)
[1] (0,1]   (-2,-1] (0,1]   (1,2]   (0,1]   (-1,0]  (-2,-1] (0,1]   (-1,0] 
12 Levels: (-6,-5] (-5,-4] (-4,-3] (-3,-2] (-2,-1] (-1,0] (0,1] (1,2] ... (5,6]
> findInterval(rnorm(9), -6:6)
[1] 7 6 7 6 8 9 7 7 6
```

Comment: I have edited my original post. I think it got buried along the old ones. Can you spot some of the errors in the above? Thanks